# Call to a member function exec() on a non-object when doing PDO::exec()

Tags: php, pdo

I am working on a PHP script to export/import some database rows from one DB to another.

So far I got this function to make sure the destination table is empty before putting new rows in there:

```
function truncateTable($conn, $tblname)
{
    echo "Truncating..";
    $query = $conn->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE $tblname") or die("failed!");
    echo "Truncated table $tblname!";
}
```

However, this is giving me this error:

```
Call to a member function exec() on a non-object
```

The connectionstring that gets passed to the function in `$conn` looks like this:

```
$con2 = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbs2;dbname=$dbd2",$dbu2,$dbp2);
```

I call the function like this:

```
truncateTable($con2, "users");
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am just learning PDO, so forgive me if this is a very basic question.

Comment: Try `$conn->exec(...)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead, you are passing `$conn` in to the method, not `$q`:

```
function truncateTable($conn, $tblname)
{
    echo "Truncating..";
    $query = $conn->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE $tblname") or die("failed!");
    echo "Truncated table $tblname!";
}
```

To fix the other issue, use `query()` instead of `exec()` :)

Comment: Correct - that was a bummer. However, now I just get "failed!" - any way to see more error info?

Answer (score 3):

One possible culprit may be DB permissions--i.e. does the MySQL user profile have sufficient privileges to TRUNCATE a table?  Intuitively that might seem like the same thing as DELETE, but it's not.  TRUNCATE requires DROP privileges (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html).

One frustrating thing about mysqli_query() is that if the web user is not allowed to DROP tables, the "...or die()" part doesn't execute--kind of passive-aggressive, IMO. ;~)

Answer (score 2):

The argument in the function is `$conn`, not `$q.`

Comment: Correct. This does however not solve my problem. Now it just prints "failed!"

Comment: @FrederikNielsen does the connected user have DROP priveleges? it is required for TRUNCATE

Comment: It works if I do it via phpMyAdmin - so the query shouldn't be wrong

Comment: @FrederikNielsen also, instead of `die("failed!");`, you could use something like `die(print_r($conn->errorInfo(),1));`

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
$clean2 = $db->query( "TRUNCATE TABLE `table`");
```

Nice and simple.